# Log4net File Appender is not logging exception in server

Tags: c#, asp.net, log4net, log4net-configuration, log4net-appender

I am using `log4net` Nuget package version `2.0.8` in a Web Application. 
Whenever any exception is raised in the application that is logged in `log.txt` file. It is working fine in local. However it is not working in server. In server only the date-time value is written into the log file but not the exception details.

Below is the configuration in the `Web.config` file:

```
<log4net>
    <appender name="LogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender,log4net">
      <param name="DatePattern" value="-yyyy-MM-dd'.txt'" />
      <param name="AppendToFile" value="true" />
      <param name="StaticLogFileName" value="true" />
      <param name="MaxSizeRollBackups" value="-1" />
      <param name="RollingStyle" value="Date" />
      <param name="CountDirection" value="1" />
      <param name="File" value="D:\Logs\log.txt" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%newline%d %property{log4net:HostName} [%t] %-5p - %m%n" />
      </layout>
      <threshold value="ERROR"/>
    </appender>
    <root>
      <priority value="All" />
      <appender-ref ref="LogFileAppender" />
    </root>
 </log4net>
```

The log4net section is also defined in the Web.config file:

```
<configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,Log4net"  requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
```

The Log object is created in the class level variable as follows:

```
 private static readonly ILog Log =           LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
```

The exception is logged like follows:

```
try
{
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
 Log.Error( "Test exception :" + ex.Message, ex);
}
```

In server only the date time is written in the log file but not the exception details. See the below image for reference:

[image: Log File Content]

In the `Global.asax` file the log4net is registered like follows:

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
}
```

Can anyone help me how can I resolve this error. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked after I changed the `log4net` settings in `Web.config` file:

```
<layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%newline%d %message" />
</layout>
```

I noticed the error log is written to the file after `~2 minutes`. So don't open the file to see the logs. Wait for ~2 minutes then open.